# How to change the IIS 7 application pool on a remote server?

Tags: windows, iis-7, scripting, nant

I am looking to create new virtual directories on a remote server and set the app pool to a configuration other than the default. I am using NAnt but open to any other commands that can accompolish this.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<mkiisdir iisserver="${remote.server}" dirpath="${install.path}" vdirname="${vir.dir.name}" />
```

The above works fine in creating the VD to a remote server but the  nant task does not have a parameter for specificing the application pool. Strange as to why not !!

I looked into using powershell to [update the application pool](http://www.iisonthe.net/2012/07/25/changing-application-pool-identities-in-iis-78-using-powershell/) since I already have the Virtual Directory created but due to my Windows OS restrictions I am unable to install the WebAdministration module which is required to update the IIS app pool.

Is there any existing method to accompolish this that I have not considered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppCmd.exe which is located in the System32 folder.

```
appcmd set app /app.name:"Default Web Site/MyVirtualDirectoryName" /applicationPool:"MyAppPool"
```

If you need to Update the web applications directories on other servers remotely, then you can use `PSExec \\RemoteServerHostname appcmd set app /app.name:"Default Web Site/MyVirtualDirectoryName" /applicationPool:"MyAppPool"`